# how to display and ignore kml layer in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a google maps where I can click on the map and markers appear:

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    draggableCursor: 'crosshair',
    draggable: true,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    }
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

Wherever I click, a function gets called to do some work (add markers).

I've been asked to add a kml layer:

```
    var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/data/polygon.cfm?TYPE=GEOID&VALUE=" + getUrlVars()["GEOID"] + "&LC=641400FF&LW=3&FC=14F11C2E&F=1&FO=1";

    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: false,
        map: map
    });
```

now, once the kml layer is added, the "crosshair" is gone, and I can't click on the map anymore.  Is there a setting in the kmlLayer that I can set that "ignores" the layer while still displaying it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a link to your kml layer?

Comment: yes, addressed to the url variable.  That's the variable in the second code block above.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, an external url so I can access your kml.  I'm doing a JS fiddle to try and assist

Comment: http://dev.buyerhero.com:81/data/polygon.cfm?TYPE=GEOID&VALUE=12117021611&LC=641400FF&LW=3&FC=14F11C2E&F=1&FO=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your KML initialization code from:

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
});
```

to

```
 var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
{
   url: url,
   suppressInfoWindows: true,  
   map:map,
   zindex: 0,
   clickable : false
});
```

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/jnrnmog4/  You can click the map and the marker which is over the KML

The key being the clickable = false property on the KML Layer option

Comment: Probably because the sample layer was no longer available.  I have updated the sample KMl layer for you.

Comment: Ahhh the problem was that I didn't know the KmlLayer would be added to the background images instead of drawn on top of it like a polyline(or any other shape). I did a CSS code mod which was hiding all images/tiles loaded from Google Maps.